# ClassFormatError: too many arguments

Tags: java, jvm

I have a method is:

```
private void doTest(boolean test_isNullExpr_0, double test_parameters_0, boolean test_isNullExpr_1, double test_parameters_1, boolean test_isNullExpr_2, double test_parameters_2, boolean test_isNullExpr_3, double test_parameters_3, boolean test_isNullExpr_4, double test_parameters_4, boolean test_isNullExpr_5, double test_parameters_5, boolean test_isNullExpr_6, double test_parameters_6, boolean test_isNullExpr_7, double test_parameters_7, boolean test_isNullExpr_8, double test_parameters_8, boolean test_isNullExpr_9, double test_parameters_9, boolean test_isNullExpr_10, double test_parameters_10, boolean test_isNullExpr_11, double test_parameters_11, boolean test_isNullExpr_12, double test_parameters_12, boolean test_isNullExpr_13, double test_parameters_13, boolean test_isNullExpr_14, double test_parameters_14, boolean test_isNullExpr_15, double test_parameters_15, boolean test_isNullExpr_16, double test_parameters_16, boolean test_isNullExpr_17, double test_parameters_17, boolean test_isNullExpr_18, double test_parameters_18, boolean test_isNullExpr_19, double test_parameters_19, boolean test_isNullExpr_20, double test_parameters_20, boolean test_isNullExpr_21, double test_parameters_21, boolean test_isNullExpr_22, double test_parameters_22, boolean test_isNullExpr_23, double test_parameters_23, boolean test_isNullExpr_24, double test_parameters_24, boolean test_isNullExpr_25, double test_parameters_25, boolean test_isNullExpr_26, double test_parameters_26, boolean test_isNullExpr_27, double test_parameters_27, boolean test_isNullExpr_28, double test_parameters_28, boolean test_isNullExpr_29, double test_parameters_29, boolean test_isNullExpr_30, double test_parameters_30, boolean test_isNullExpr_31, double test_parameters_31, boolean test_isNullExpr_32, double test_parameters_32, boolean test_isNullExpr_33, double test_parameters_33, boolean test_isNullExpr_34, double test_parameters_34, boolean test_isNullExpr_35, double test_parameters_35, boolean test_isNullExpr_36, double test_parameters_36, boolean test_isNullExpr_37, double test_parameters_37, boolean test_isNullExpr_38, double test_parameters_38, boolean test_isNullExpr_39, double test_parameters_39, boolean test_isNullExpr_40, double test_parameters_40, boolean test_isNullExpr_41, double test_parameters_41, boolean test_isNullExpr_42, double test_parameters_42, boolean test_isNullExpr_43, double test_parameters_43, boolean test_isNullExpr_44, double test_parameters_44, boolean test_isNullExpr_45, double test_parameters_45, boolean test_isNullExpr_46, double test_parameters_46, boolean test_isNullExpr_47, double test_parameters_47, boolean test_isNullExpr_48, double test_parameters_48, boolean test_isNullExpr_49, double test_parameters_49, boolean test_isNullExpr_50, double test_parameters_50, boolean test_isNullExpr_51, double test_parameters_51, boolean test_isNullExpr_52, double test_parameters_52, boolean test_isNullExpr_53, double test_parameters_53, boolean test_isNullExpr_54, double test_parameters_54, boolean test_isNullExpr_55, double test_parameters_55, boolean test_isNullExpr_56, double test_parameters_56, boolean test_isNullExpr_57, double test_parameters_57, boolean test_isNullExpr_58, double test_parameters_58, boolean test_isNullExpr_59, double test_parameters_59, boolean test_isNullExpr_60, double test_parameters_60, boolean test_isNullExpr_61, double test_parameters_61, boolean test_isNullExpr_62, double test_parameters_62, boolean test_isNullExpr_63, double test_parameters_63, boolean test_isNullExpr_64, double test_parameters_64, boolean test_isNullExpr_65, double test_parameters_65, boolean test_isNullExpr_66, double test_parameters_66, boolean test_isNullExpr_67, double test_parameters_67, boolean test_isNullExpr_68, double test_parameters_68, boolean test_isNullExpr_69, double test_parameters_69, boolean test_isNullExpr_70, double test_parameters_70, boolean test_isNullExpr_71, double test_parameters_71, boolean test_isNullExpr_72, double test_parameters_72, boolean test_isNullExpr_73, double test_parameters_73, boolean test_isNullExpr_74, double test_parameters_74, boolean test_isNullExpr_75, double test_parameters_75, boolean test_isNullExpr_76, double test_parameters_76, boolean test_isNullExpr_77, double test_parameters_77, boolean test_isNullExpr_78, double test_parameters_78, boolean test_isNullExpr_79, double test_parameters_79, boolean test_isNullExpr_80, double test_parameters_80, boolean test_isNullExpr_81, double test_parameters_81, boolean test_isNullExpr_82, double test_parameters_82, boolean test_isNullExpr_83, double test_parameters_83, boolean test_isNullExpr_84, double test_parameters_84) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("hihihi");
}
```

but the number of parameters do not exceeded 255 that the jvm limits, why?

Comment: Is ClassFormatError some kind of exception? I got compilation error: `Too many parameters, parameter test_parameters_84 is exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters`

Comment: I know the reason：The number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of a method descriptor (§4.3.3), where the limit includes one unit for this in the case of instance or interface method invocations.

Note that a method descriptor is defined in terms of a notion of method parameter length in which a parameter of type long or double contributes two units to the length, so parameters of these types further reduce the limit.